# AddEventListener and image loader trouble

Tags: javascript, image, events, addeventlistener

I had problem with event listener and image loader in my code. When i try to load and check status of loaded image based on event listener some of images skipped. I think browser can handle only one event and when active one isn't stopped next can work and skip its work. So few of images return wront status and can be used. Just give me some advices about this. Here is my code:

```
//Image loader
var urlList = [ 
    'images/ground_02.png', // 0 - FG
    'images/ground_layer0.png', // 1 - CITY
        ...
];
var urlListLength = urlList.length; //length of URL-array
var iCount = new Number(0); // Create zero-counter
var images = new Array(); // All images array. Each elem stores one image
var imageInfo = function(imageName, imageCount, imageWidth, imageHeight) { // Constructor for image data container
    this.imageName = imageName; // Url of image
    this.imageCount = imageCount; // Frames
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth; // Width of images
    this.imageHeight = imageHeight; // Height of images
}; 
var imageData = new Array(); // Images data array
for (var i=0; i!=urlListLength; ++i) { // Loop for each image load
    images[i] = new Image(); // Image array.
    images[i].addEventListener('load', function(i) {

        imageData.push(new imageInfo(images[iCount], images[iCount].width/images[iCount].height, images[iCount].width, images[iCount].height));

        iCount++;
        if (iCount == urlListLength) {
            var loaded = true;
            loop();
        };

    }, false);

    images[i].src = urlList[i];
    images[i].onerror=function() {
        alert("FAIL "+this.src);
    };

};
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to make it clearer what question you're asking? And have you tried to confirm your thoughts about the cause?

Comment: How do you test if some image is loaded or not?

Comment: You should define onerror *before* setting the src.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all browsers, including IE6.

```
var list = [
      'images/ground_02.png',
      'images/ground_layer0.png'
    ],
    images = {};

function loadImage() {
  images[this.src] = {
    loaded: (this.width > 0 ? true : false),
    src: this.src,
    width: this.width,
    height: this.height
  };

  if (list.length < 1) return;

  var url = list.pop(),
      img = new Image();

  img.onload = loadImage;
  img.onerror = loadImage;
  img.src = url;
}

loadImage(); // Initialize loading
```

And if you need to check if an image has been loaded:

```
function isImageLoaded(src) {
  return (images[src] && images[src].loaded);
}

if (isImageLoaded('images/ground_02.png')) alert('Yes!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem at least here:

```
imageData.push(new imageInfo(images[iCount], images[iCount].width/images[iCount].height, images[iCount].width, images[iCount].height));
```

`load` event is fired once image is loaded by browser. But it is not necessary that it will be fired in the same order as load is started. Basically, `images[2]` could be loaded before `images[0]` and `images[1]` and in that case iCount won't work.

You can use `this` instead of `images[iCount]` as in this case `this` will point to exact that image which has fired load event.

```
imageData.push(new imageInfo(this, this.width/this.height, this.width, this.height));
```

> I think browser can handle only one event and when active one isn't
>   stopped next can work and skip its work.

Nope. That is wrong. Regularly all events will be fired. But JS is single threaded, so it will simply put an event into a queue and will run next event after previous is done. It will not skip any event.